# How to set up loss function in PyTorch for Soft-Actor-Critic

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, autograd

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function for a soft Q-learning, actor-critic policy gradient algorithm in PyTorch. This comes from the following paper [Learning from Imperfect Demonstrations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05313.pdf). The structure of the algorithm is similar to deep q-learning, in that we are using a network to estimate Q-values, and we use a target network to stabilize results. Unlike DQN, however, we calculate V(s) from Q(s) by:

[image]

This is simple enough to calculate with PyTorch. My main question has to do with how to set up the loss function. Part of the update equation is expressed as:

[image]

Note that Q_hat comes from the target network. How can I go about putting something like this into a loss function? I can compute values for V and Q, but how can I handle the gradients in this case? If anyone can point me towards a similar example that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be fairly simple assuming you can calculate V, Q, and Q^. After discussing this with some people offline I was able to get pytorch to calculate this loss by setting it up as:

```
loss = (Q-V)*(Q-Q_hat).detach()
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```